# Node.js mongodb cursor.each get empty, can't run in sequence

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
server.get('/getlist', function (req, res, next) {
    db.collection('lists',function(error, collection) {
        var gets = [];
        var cursor = collection.find({status: 1});
        var i = 0;
        cursor.each(function (err, docs) {
            console.log(docs);
            gets[i] = docs;
            i = i + 1;
        });
        res.send(gets);
    });

    return next();
});
```

It can log out correctly, but the website "`http://127.0.0.1:8080/getlist`" result is empty "[]".
How to make cursor.each run in sequence every source code line? Or is there any better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use toArray to convert cursor into array:

```
cursor.toArray(function(err,documents){
   res.send(documents);
   next();
});
```